# SQL - Combining AND & OR

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, boolean-logic

I have the following code:

```
SELECT sdd.sd_doc_classification,
       sdd.sd_title,
       sdd.sd_desc,
       sdr.sd_upload_fname
FROM sdoc_docs AS sdd
INNER JOIN sdoc_revh AS sdr ON sdd.sd_id = sdr.sd_id
WHERE (sdd.sd_title LIKE '%policy%')
    OR (sdd.sd_title LIKE '%guideline%')
    AND (sdd.sd_doc_classification NOT LIKE '%\Trust Wide Policies & Guidelines\%')
```

However, adding  "`OR (sdd.sd_title LIKE '%guideline%')`" has broken it and the statement now returns values that **are** like `'%\Trust Wide Policies & Guidelines\%'`.

The code runs as intended after removing the guideline example above.

Essentially I want to display anything that has an `sd_title` like `policy` or `guideline` and doesn't have `sd_doc_classification` like `'%trust wide pol%'`.

Comment: Just use parentheses correctly.

Comment: Whenever you mix `AND` and `OR` you should always add parens. The precedence is `NOT`-`AND`-`OR`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AND` has a higher precedence than `OR` - i.e., it's as if you'd written your query like this:

```
SELECT sdd.sd_doc_classification,
       sdd.sd_title,
       sdd.sd_desc,
       sdr.sd_upload_fname
FROM       sdoc_docs AS sdd
INNER JOIN sdoc_revh AS sdr ON sdd.sd_id = sdr.sd_id
WHERE      (sdd.sd_title LIKE '%policy%') OR 
           ((sdd.sd_title LIKE '%guideline%') AND 
            (sdd.sd_doc_classification NOT LIKE 
             '%\Trust Wide Policies & Guidelines\%'))
```

If you want to control the precedence the conditions are evaluated, you can explicitly add parentheses yourself:

```
SELECT sdd.sd_doc_classification,
       sdd.sd_title,
       sdd.sd_desc,
       sdr.sd_upload_fname
FROM       sdoc_docs AS sdd
INNER JOIN sdoc_revh AS sdr ON sdd.sd_id = sdr.sd_id
WHERE      ((sdd.sd_title LIKE '%policy%') OR 
            (sdd.sd_title LIKE '%guideline%')) AND 
           (sdd.sd_doc_classification NOT LIKE 
             '%\Trust Wide Policies & Guidelines\%')
```

Comment: This works, and makes a lot of sense now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Gordon and dnoeth, your parentheses are the problem. I think you actually need the following query.

```
SELECT sdd.sd_doc_classification,
       sdd.sd_title,
       sdd.sd_desc,
       sdr.sd_upload_fname
FROM sdoc_docs AS sdd
INNER JOIN sdoc_revh AS sdr ON sdd.sd_id = sdr.sd_id
WHERE 
    (
        sdd.sd_title LIKE '%policy%'
        OR 
        sdd.sd_title LIKE '%guideline%'
    )
    AND 
    sdd.sd_doc_classification NOT LIKE '%\Trust Wide Policies & Guidelines\%'
```

I find correctly tabbing out the different OR and AND clauses clearly makes them easier to visualise and understand.

Comment: This also works, and makes sense. I can see what i've done wrong now. Thanks!